# Apache2.2 - PHP5.3 - MySQL5.5 - MantisBT

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mantis

Having a little trouble here with Apache 2.2 & PHP 5.3 & MySQL 5.5, seems PHP sees the MySQL module, the relevant parts have been added or un-commented and the DLL file does exists in the c:\php\ folder, but when I go to set up Mantis and run the setup, I get the below error.

Any obvious issues people have experienced with this?
If need be I can add my php.ini or httpd.conf, but I don't see any more config to be added to them than I have shown in the attachment below.

Cheers in advance

KS

[image]

---

This should trow a little more light on the subject (from the Apache error.log):-

> PHP Warning:  **PHP Startup: mysql: Unable to initialize module\nModule
>   compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS,VC9\nPHP    compiled with build
>   ID=API20090626,TS,VC9\nThese** options need to match\n in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Warning:  **PHP Startup: mysqli: Unable to initialize
>   module\nModule compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS,VC9\nPHP
>
>   compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9**\nThese options need to
>   match\n in Unknown on line 0 [Wed Apr 24 11:07:21 2013] [notice]
>   Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.23 configured -- resuming normal
>   operations ...

I'm using:

PHP v5.3.23

Apche v2.2.22

MySQL v5.5.30

Comment: Shouldn't your have PostgreSQL module activated in order to use Mantis ?

Comment: Hope not (mantis requirements page) -- MySQL database 4.1.1 and higher (MS SQL, DB2, and PostgreSQL are also supported).

Comment: Do you have any more details on the /check.php page ? Saw some answers there http://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=666 but can't test the "solution" given.

Answer (score 0):

**SORTED!**

Not sure how or why, but when I first installed PHP I used this *php-5.3.23-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.msi* installer and was getting the above error. I downloaded this zip *php-5.3.23-Win32-VC9-x86.zip* and used the mysql.dll and mysqli.dll from the zips /ext folder and replaced the DLLs in the installed c:\php\ext folder. Then restarted Apache and - bingo! worked!

The sizes and dates of the DLLs from the zip are slightly different tothe ones in the MSI install, so there must be a slight variation.

Phew - and *they* say PHP is simple to use, give my JSP pages any day!